# Can I change vertex buffer's size?

Tags: c++, directx11, vertex-buffer

Maybe it's a stupid question but I actually don't know - is it possible to change vertex buffer's size after it's been already created (with `CreateBuffer()`)? If so, how do I update its data (with both `Map()` and `UpdateSubresource()`) when the new data contains more/less vertices?

I'm interested in vertex buffers and dx11 but the question probably applies also to index buffers and opengl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, at least in D3D11 it is not possible to change the size of a buffer or texture after it's been allocated.  You would have to release the old buffer and create a new one (which is inadvisable to do often, as it can hurt performance).

It's okay to only use part of a vertex buffer, so if you know the maximum size your data will be, I'd allocate the buffer to that size; then you can just write to and draw from as much of it as you need in a given frame.